# AngularJS $q in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I need to implement a $q deferred in that way the getRoutesTest method to return me routesArr array only after all computations are done.

I need to extract all distances from some routes and then compare it.

How may I extract distances on an asynchronous call?

Service:

```
app.factory('testServ', function ($q) {
    var getData = {};

    getData.getRoutesTest = function (chkdMksPos, fromArr) {
        var dest = []; var routesArr = []; var destArr = [];
        var promise = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < chkdMksPos.length; i++) {
            var lat = chkdMksPos[i].lat(); var lng = chkdMksPos[i].lng();
            dest.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
        var distanceMatrixRequest = { origins: fromArr, destinations: dest, travelMode: 'DRIVING' };
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(distanceMatrixRequest, function (response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                promise = callback(response);
                console.log(promise);
            } else {
                console.log("Status is NOT OK");
            }
        });

        function callback(response) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                var from = origins[i];
                var routes;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var element = results[j];   var to = destinations[j];
                    var distText    = element.distance.text;    var distValue   = element.distance.value;
                    var timeText    = element.duration.text;    var timeValue   = element.duration.value;
                    var destElem = { "destination": to, "distance": { "text": distText, "value": distValue }, "duration": { "text": timeText, "value": timeValue } };
                    destArr.push(destElem);
                }
                routes = { "origin": from, "destArr": destArr };
                deferred.resolve(routesArr.push(routes));
            }
            console.log("!!! routesArr before return = " + routesArr.length);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        console.log("!!! routesArr after return = " + routesArr.length);
        return promise;
    };

    return getData;
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$window', '$timeout', '$q', 'testServ',
function($scope, $filter, $window, $timeout, $q, testServ) {
    $scope.tryAgain = function () {
        $scope.$watch(function() { return $window.google; }, function() {
            if (typeof $window.google != 'undefined') {
                console.log('Variabila "google" a fost initializata');

                var geoArr = [];
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.1, 23.3);
                geoArr.push(latLng);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.1, 27.3);
                geoArr.push(latLng);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.1, 22.3);
                geoArr.push(latLng);

                var fromArr = [];
                fromArr.push("Timisoara");
                fromArr.push("Bacau");

                $scope.promise = testServ.getRoutesTest(geoArr, fromArr);
                console.log("test = " + $scope.promise);
            } else {
                console.log('ERROR: NU pot initializa variabila "google"');
            }
        });
    };

    $timeout($scope.tryAgain, 500); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Service:

```
app.factory('testServ', function ($q) {
    var getData = {};

    getData.getRoutesTest = function (chkdMksPos, fromArr) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var dest = []; var routesArr = []; var destArr = [];
        var promise = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < chkdMksPos.length; i++) {
            var lat = chkdMksPos[i].lat(); var lng = chkdMksPos[i].lng();
            dest.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
        var distanceMatrixRequest = { origins: fromArr, destinations: dest, travelMode: 'DRIVING' };
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(distanceMatrixRequest, function (response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                promise = callback(response);
                deferred.resolve(promise);
                //console.log(promise);
            } else {
                console.log("Status is NOT OK");
            }
        });

        function callback(response) {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                var from = origins[i];
                var routes;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var element = results[j];                               var to = destinations[j];
                    var distText    = element.distance.text;    var distValue   = element.distance.value;
                    var timeText    = element.duration.text;    var timeValue   = element.duration.value;
                    var destElem = { "destination": to, "distance": { "text": distText, "value": distValue }, "duration": { "text": timeText, "value": timeValue } };
                    destArr.push(destElem);
                }
                routes = { "origin": from, "destArr": destArr };
                routesArr.push(routes);
            }
            return routesArr;
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return getData;
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$window', '$timeout', '$q', 'testServ',
function($scope, $filter, $window, $timeout, $q, testServ) {
    $scope.tryAgain = function () {
        $scope.$watch(function() { return $window.google; }, function() {
            if (typeof $window.google != 'undefined') {
                console.log('Variabila "google" a fost initializata');
                $scope.out = [];

                var geoArr = [];
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.1, 23.3);
                geoArr.push(latLng);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.1, 27.3);
                geoArr.push(latLng);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.1, 22.3);
                geoArr.push(latLng);

                var fromArr = [];
                fromArr.push("Timisoara");
                fromArr.push("Bacau");              

                var dataPromise = testServ.getRoutesTest(geoArr, fromArr);
                dataPromise.then(function(data) {
                    console.log('Success!', data);
                    $scope.out = data;
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('Failure...', error);
                });

                $scope.$watch('out', function() {
                    console.log($scope.out);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('ERROR: NU pot initializa variabila "google"');
            }
        });
    };

    $timeout($scope.tryAgain, 500); 
}]);
```